# Load Parcelable from Bundle after refactoring

Tags: android

How can I change the package of a `Parcelable` class while still being able to load persisted `Bundle`s?

I tried having a custom class loader load the new class when presented with the old class name but all it does is throw `NoClassDefFoundError` insteaf of `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
class ClassLoaderCompat(parent: ClassLoader) : ClassLoader(parent) {

   override fun loadClass(name: String): Class<*>? {
      return if (name == "my.old.class.package.MyClass") {
         my.new.class.package.MyClass::class.java
      } else {
         super.loadClass(name)
      }
   }
}
```

There is the callstack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Initiating class loader of type fulguris.utils.ClassLoaderCompat returned class fulguris.browser.sessions.Session instead of acr.browser.lightning.browser.sessions.Session.
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3338)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3272)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3174)
at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3630)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2758)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3195)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3567)
at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:291)
at fulguris.utils.FileUtils.readBundleFromStorage(FileUtils.java:126)
at fulguris.browser.TabsManager.loadSessions(TabsManager.kt:830)
at fulguris.browser.TabsManager.restorePreviousTabs(TabsManager.kt:443)
at fulguris.browser.TabsManager.tryRestorePreviousTabs(TabsManager.kt:466)
at fulguris.browser.TabsManager.initializeTabs(TabsManager.kt:291)
at fulguris.browser.TabsManager$setupTabs$1.invokeSuspend(TabsManager.kt:980)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:518)
at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

It seems that's a limitation of the JVM use of ClassLoader.

What's the best way to persist classes to file while still being able to refactor and extend them?

Comment: you forgot to include the code of classloader, i.e. example etc

Comment: Added `ClassLoader` I used but apparently you can't do that. Too bad cause it would give an easy path forward to refactor persisted bundled classes.